# Как использовать функцию LEAD для расчета времени между текущим и последующим событием?

Tags: sql, oracle

У меня есть таблица `test1`, в которой находятся данные о расписании поездов:

```
ID  NEXT_ID TRAIN_ID DATE_START             DATE_END
1   2       5        06.11.2019 5:00:00     06.11.2019 7:40:00
2   3       5        06.11.2019 8:00:00     06.11.2019 9:00:00
3   4       5        06.11.2019 10:00:00    06.11.2019 10:15:00
4   5       5        06.11.2019 23:05:00    07.11.2019 0:15:00
5   6       5        07.11.2019 2:05:00     07.11.2019 4:30:00
6   7       5        07.11.2019 5:05:00     07.11.2019 7:05:00
7   8       5        07.11.2019 9:05:00     07.11.2019 10:05:00
8           5        07.11.2019 12:05:00    07.11.2019 14:05:00
```

Где `ID` - идентификатор поездки, `NEXT_ID` - отсылка на следующую поездку в расписании, `TRAIN_ID` - номер поезда (в данном вопросе для простоты я оставил один, но может быть несколько поездов), `DATE_START` и `DATE_END` значат время начала и конца поездки соответственно.

Надо найти время "простоев" между поездками. Например, между поездками с `ID` 1 и 2 простой будет 8:00-7:40 = 20 минут, с `ID` 2 и 3 10:00-9:00 = 60 минут, и так далее.

Пробовал сделать эту задачу с функцией `LEAD`, но я явно использую ее как-то не так:

```
SELECT  id, train_id, next_id, 
LEAD(next_id) OVER (ORDER BY next_id) next_code,
dt_start, dt_end,
Round(( date_end - date_start) * 24) as prost_hour
FROM test1
```

Прошу помочь разобраться.

Comment: *Найти время "простоев" между поездками.* Это должен быть простой до следующего рейса или простой после предыдущего? *я явно использую ее как-то не так.* 1) Вряд ли в таблице только один поезд (`TRAIN_ID`) - если нет, то в определении окна должен быть ещё и PARTITION BY. 2) Нафига Вам следующий идентификатор записи (`next_id`), если нужно время из неё?

Comment: 1) Простой от времени приезда одного рейса до времени отъезда следующего рейса. 2) Next_id нужен, если `ID` идут не друг за другом. Например, сначала идет рейс одного поезда под `ID` = 5, а следующий будет в `ID` = 8. В примере такого нет, но потенциально может быть.

Comment: Мля... между рейсами 1 и 2 зазор 20 минут. Он должен отображаться в строке 1 или в строке 2? *Next_id нужен, если ID идут не друг за другом.* Да он вообще не нужен. Сортировки по дате-времени достаточно. *В примере такого нет, но потенциально может быть* Всё, что может быть - должно быть в примере.

Comment: Кстати, это хороший вопрос. Не знаю, есть ли разница, но пусть будет в строке 1.

Comment: *Не знаю, есть ли разница* Есть. В зависимости от этого надо использовать разные функции либо разные определения окна.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот воспроизводимый пример для Oracle (тестовые данные на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b9d350c32fb49f22248109451b03f62b)):

```
select train_id, date_start, date_end, 
    lead (date_start) over (partition by train_id order by date_start) next_start,
    to_char (
        date'1970-01-01' +
        (lead (date_start) over (partition by train_id order by date_start)-date_end), 
        'hh24:mi:ss') diff
from test t
order by train_id, date_start;
```

Результат:

```
  TRAIN_ID DATE_START          DATE_END            NEXT_START          DIFF    
---------- ------------------- ------------------- ------------------- --------
         5 2019-11-06 05:00:00 2019-11-06 07:40:00 2019-11-06 08:00:00 00:20:00
         5 2019-11-06 08:00:00 2019-11-06 09:00:00 2019-11-06 10:00:00 01:00:00
         5 2019-11-06 10:00:00 2019-11-06 10:15:00 2019-11-06 23:05:00 12:50:00
         5 2019-11-06 23:05:00 2019-11-07 00:15:00 2019-11-07 02:05:00 01:50:00
         5 2019-11-07 02:05:00 2019-11-07 04:30:00 2019-11-07 05:05:00 00:35:00
         5 2019-11-07 05:05:00 2019-11-07 07:05:00 2019-11-07 09:05:00 02:00:00
         5 2019-11-07 09:05:00 2019-11-07 10:05:00 2019-11-07 12:05:00 02:00:00
         5 2019-11-07 12:05:00 2019-11-07 14:05:00                             
         6 2019-11-06 06:00:00 2019-11-06 07:40:00 2019-11-06 09:00:00 01:20:00
         6 2019-11-06 09:00:00 2019-11-06 09:50:00 2019-11-06 12:00:00 02:10:00
         6 2019-11-06 12:00:00 2019-11-06 13:15:00 2019-11-06 14:05:00 00:50:00
         6 2019-11-06 14:05:00 2019-11-07 00:15:00
```

---

<sub>Перевод ответа от уважаемого коллеги [@Akina](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1181918).</sub>

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Comment: Рад был помочь!

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT *,
       LEAD(DATE_START) OVER (PARTITION BY TRAIN_ID ORDER BY DATE_START) next_start,
       TIMEDIFF(LEAD(DATE_START) OVER (PARTITION BY TRAIN_ID ORDER BY DATE_START), DATE_END) delta
FROM test
ORDER BY train_id, date_start;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=267e9134fb9ce99eaa3ae46f01c14f12)

---

PS fiddle сделан в MySQL. Для Oracle придётся разве что подправить `TIMEDIFF`, всё остальное один-в-один.

PPS Всё-таки колонка `NEXT_ID` не нужна, т.к. порядок чётко определяется временем. Конечно при условии, что в данных нет ошибок.

Comment: А какие сложности были дать пример сразу для oracle?

Comment: @0xdb А у него постоянный геморрой какой-то - то ему по одной строке на блок, то FROM DUAL, то ещё чего... а я его редко пользую, рука не набита... лень, короче. Но если кто создаст свой ответ с переписанным под Оракл кодом - так я не против.

Comment: Ааа, лень это уважительная причина.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.